# Google Calendar API ClassDefNotFoundException

Tags: android, google-api, google-calendar-api

I'm a new developer and I'm trying to use the Google Calender API.  I followed the insturctions from http://code.google.com/apis/calendar/v3/using.html#setup and copied and pasted the example code.  When I try to launch the setup method from my app it crashes with a ClassDefNotFoundException and it's on the org.codehaus.jackson.JsonFactory class.  I've tried almost everything.  Can somebody give me an idea on what I'm doing wrong?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Follow the [instructions](http://code.google.com/p/google-api-java-client/wiki/Android#Installation) about installing Google API java client for android

Answer (score 0):

You would appear to be missing the Jackson JAR, which is the source of the class that you are missing. Download the appropriate version and add it to your project (e.g., put it in your `libs/` directory and add it to your Eclipse build path)..

Comment: I did follow those instructions which by the way never say I need to start adding the jars from the dependency folder.  I've run into another problem now.  When I start adding the jars to my build path eclipse gets very, very slow and even crashes fairly often.  Also when I add the guava jar my project fails to build and eclipse gives me "Conversion to Dalvik format failed with error 1".  Removeing the jar from the build path and everything is good again although very slow.  What am I doing wrong?  Thanks